# facebook audience network always quality check fail

Tags: facebook, facebook-audience-network, fraud-prevention

**facebook audience network always quality check fail.**

I followed all best practices which show on this link. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/best-practices

and uploaded many app with various ads placement but no success. whenever i try to contact Facebook team about this issue they always say's we can tell you anything now follow our guideline.

Now i seen that once my app started to earn 50$ they fail quality check. and stop sending revenue, even if i am not getting any revenue but in my app Facebook ads is visible in free for which they will not paying anything.

Is there anyone having solution for this issue ?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Had to archive the placement. Tried everything that their guideline suggested. Nothing works. Emailing them has no effect. They don't tell anything about what to improve! Did you find out something?

Comment: Hi, @vivek. I am new to facebook audience network. I have a quite few app on facebook audience network. If any of them fail quality check issue, then does it stop sending payment for all other apps?

Comment: Hi @Vikas you got any Solution about this, Admob working fine and same placement not working form Facebook Audience Network, kindly tell me if you found any solution.

Comment: still not found any solution, there are new option to remove placement which fail in quality check and 90% case quality check fail is cause of banner.

Comment: @Saikat1529 there are not an issue with payment, payment will be paid if you reach to threshold , but you can't not further monetise with same app using facebook. there is no solution for this issue.

Comment: Load your ad at same time with the content.

Comment: @Quimbo Please explain your answer. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Even I had this problem and I couldn't solve it for long time. I recently got to chat with the support and the possible reasons is that creating unwanted ad placements and ad units which is idle will affect our revenue a lot.

so here's some tips that I got from them and hope it helps you too :)

- Remove all the unnecessary ad placements which are idle.
- Set the CPM to default and do not set any changes for it.
- Make sure the ads are placed properly that does not manipulate the users by forcing
  them to click the ads.
- Do not self click.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Added privacy policy and fixed a crash and made an appeal. My app got later approved with the appeal.